# How to convert [TYPE] to nullable<[TYPE]> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nullable, activator

Question:

I wrote a method to retrieve a SQL result as a list of a class instead of a datatable.
The problem is, I have a int field in the database, which is nullable.

If I hit a row with a `NULL` `int`, `DataReader` returns `DbNull.Value` instead of null.
So `System.Convert.ChangeType(objVal, fi.FieldType)` throws an exception, because it can't convert `DbNull` to an `int`.

So far so bad.
I thought I had solved the problem, when I just compared `objVal` to `DbNull.Value` and if true, did this instead:
`System.Convert.ChangeType(null, fi.FieldType)`

unfortunately, I just realized, the resulting integer type is 0 instead of NULL.

So I just tried changing the int type in my class to `Nullable<int>`, but now I have the problem that when a value is not `DbNull.Value`, `ChangeType` throws an exception because it can't convert `int` to `nullable<int>`...

So now I try to detect the type of the object returned by `datareader`, and convert it to a nullable value.

`tTypeForNullable`  is correctly shown as `Nullable<int>`.
But when I look at the result type, I get: `int`.

Why is that ? And more important: How can I do that properly ?

**Please note that because type is an object, I can't use a generic method to create `Nullable<int>`.**

```
bool bisnull = IsNullable(objVal);
bool bisnullt = IsNullable(fi.FieldType);

if (bisnullt)
{
    Type tTypeForNullable = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(objVal.GetType());

    //object result = Activator.CreateInstance(tTypeForNullable, new object[] { objVal });
    //object result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Nullable<int>), new object[] { objVal });
    object result = Activator.CreateInstance(tTypeForNullable, objVal);
    Type tres = result.GetType();
    fi.SetValue(tThisValue, System.Convert.ChangeType(result, fi.FieldType));
}
```

Here's the complete routine for reference:

```
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> GetList<T>(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<T> lsReturnValue = new System.Collections.Generic.List<T>();
            T tThisValue = default(T);
            Type t = typeof(T);

            lock (cmd)
            {
                using (System.Data.IDataReader idr = ExecuteReader(cmd))
                {

                    lock (idr)
                    {

                        while (idr.Read())
                        {
                            //idr.GetOrdinal("")
                            tThisValue = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                            // Console.WriteLine(idr.FieldCount);
                            for (int i = 0; i < idr.FieldCount; ++i)
                            {
                                string strName = idr.GetName(i);
                                object objVal = idr.GetValue(i);


                                System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = t.GetField(strName);
                                //Type tttttt = fi.FieldType;
                                if (fi != null)
                                {
                                    //fi.SetValue(tThisValue, System.Convert.ChangeType(objVal, fi.FieldType));
                                    if (objVal == System.DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        objVal = null;
                                        fi.SetValue(tThisValue, null);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter conv = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(fi.FieldType);

                                        bool bisnull = IsNullable(objVal);
                                        bool bisnullt = IsNullable(fi.FieldType);

                                        if (bisnullt)
                                        {
                                            Type tTypeForNullable = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(objVal.GetType());

                                            //object result = Activator.CreateInstance(tTypeForNullable, new object[] { objVal });
                                            //object result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Nullable<int>), new object[] { objVal });
                                            object result = Activator.CreateInstance(tTypeForNullable, objVal);
                                            Type tres = result.GetType();
                                            fi.SetValue(tThisValue, System.Convert.ChangeType(result, fi.FieldType));
                                        }
                                        fi.SetValue(tThisValue, System.Convert.ChangeType(objVal, fi.FieldType));
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(strName);
                                    if (pi != null)
                                    {
                                        //pi.SetValue(tThisValue, System.Convert.ChangeType(objVal, pi.PropertyType), null);


                                        if (objVal == System.DBNull.Value)
                                        {
                                            objVal = null;
                                            pi.SetValue(tThisValue, null, null);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            pi.SetValue(tThisValue, System.Convert.ChangeType(objVal, pi.PropertyType), null);
                                        }


                                    }
                                    // Else silently ignore value
                                } // End else of if (fi != null)

                                //Console.WriteLine(strName);
                            } // Next i

                            lsReturnValue.Add(tThisValue);
                        } // Whend

                        idr.Close();
                    } // End Lock idr

                } // End Using idr

            } // End lock cmd

            return lsReturnValue;
        } // End Function GetList
```

with this:

```
public System.Data.IDataReader ExecuteReader(System.Data.IDbCommand cmd)
        {
            System.Data.IDataReader idr = null;

            lock(cmd)
            {
                System.Data.IDbConnection idbc = GetConnection();
                cmd.Connection = idbc;

                if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                idr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            } // End Lock cmd

            return idr;
        } // End Function ExecuteReader
```

**Please note that because type is an object, I can't use a generic method to create `Nullable<int>`.**

Comment: Have you seen Entity Framework ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Bas: Yes, and it's way too slow.

Comment: but much faster than reflection, and if you use AsNoTracking it will be almost as fast as a datareader

Comment: i have just come across this same problem and i'm coming to the opinion that it is just not possible in c# to set the value of a nullable<> type using reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're boxing - and the result of a boxing operation for a nullable value type is *never* a boxed value of that type. It's either null or a non-nullable value type. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @Quandary: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, to be honest. Is the problem "setting a nullable field by reflection"? It would be worth isolating this from database aspects etc.

Comment: The real problem is that System.Convert.ChangeType does not work for nullable types. But I just saw that the field of origin for my int was in fact a varchar... That's why convert was necessary. Now with nullable, everything works fine, i just may not call convert if fi.FieldType is nullable.

Comment: @Quandary: I don't think that's really your core problem - you don't need to solve *that*, you need to solve setting your field with reflection, right? If `ChangeType` doesn't help you for that when it's null, don't use it.

Comment: @John Skeet: Without ChangeType, you can't directly read a varchar into an int field, which is kindof a pitty. With ChangeType, it maps NULL to 0. The thought process was that with Nullable<int>, Convert would set NULL to NULL. Now I see why it cannot be done: Convert cannot return a Nullable type as Object, because that would remove the nullable from the returned type... The only question that remains is: what sense does this object-boxing behaviour make...That makes it impossible to have anything like convert for nullable types. Maybe you should update your response to: "this cannot be done"

Comment: @Quandary - Just store the integer value into a integer variable that is **nullable**.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes Ramhound, if there were only integer variables this would be possible. But this should work for all kind of variable  types (string, boolean, datetime, float, decimal, double, int, int64, char - at runtime and not at compile-time), which requires object and disallows generics, and that's the point.